# How to install vboxnetflt and vboxnetadp kernel modules on Arch Linux guest?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch-linux

I am attempting to create an Arch Linux Virtualbox 4.2.6 guest, and I have need of a Host-Only network. I have read in multiple places that I need to load the kernel modules vboxnetflt and vboxnetadp in order for this to work. However, these do not exist on my system:

```
# modprobe -a vboxnetflt vboxnetadp
modprobe: WARNING: Module vboxnetflt not found
modprobe: WARNING: Module vboxnetadp not found
```

Indeed, running a `updatedb && locate vboxnetadp` returns no results whatsoever. I have the following packages installed:

```
community/virtualbox-guest-dkms 4.2.6-1
community/virtualbox-guest-modules 4.2.6-3
community/virtualbox-guest-utils 4.2.6-1
```

`dkms install vboxguest/4.2.6` only installed vboxguest, vboxsf, and vboxvideo (which I already had). No amount of searching has led me to a place where I can find the needed modules. Any ideas?

Edit: Grawity's answer below is correct. It turns out that the reason I was having issues getting the host-only network to work correctly is because the adapter's IP on Windows must be set to the gateway IP that Linux reports when it obtains an IP. Since the IP my VM was given was in the 172.16.1.x/24 subnet, I ran the following command in a Windows shell:

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" --ip 172.16.1.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These modules are ineffective in guests – they are only for use in the VirtualBox host. `vboxnetflt` is needed for "bridged" networking mode, and `vboxnetadp` is for creating the "host-only" interfaces. Both come in the *virtualbox-host-modules* package.

**You do not need to load anything network-related in the guest.** VirtualBox already emulates the network card, anyway.